# Bulk exporting SQL Server 7 data and bulk importing it to SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, bcp

Like the title suggests, I want to bulk export data within an sql server 7.0 database into a file and then import it to an sql server 2008 r2 database, I did the following, I first typed this command on the windows 2000 shell:

```
C:> bcp sticom.dbo.societe format nul -c -f C:\test.fmt -t, -T
```

it was executed successfully, then I copied the C:\test.fmt in a network shared folder so I can access it from the other windows 7 system, I then copied on the desktop and tried to execute this command on the command prompt:

```
C:\ bcp sticom.dbo.societe in C:\test.bcp -f C:\test.fmt  -T
```

and I got this error:

> SQLState = 08001, NativeError = 2   Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server
>   Native Client 10.0][SQL Native Client]An error has occurred while
>   establishing a connection to the server. When connecting to SQL Server
>   2005, this failure may be caused by the fact that under the default
>   settings SQL Server does not allow remote connections. SQLState =
>   S1T00, NativeError = 0 Error = [Microsoft][SQL Native Client]Login
>   timeout expired

I checked my connection, I checked the services and the paths, everything was in place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [BCP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) utility attempts to connect to the **default** instance if you don't specify the -S parameter.  My guess is there is no default instance available for the 'import' BCP.

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: Is your 'import' command running on a server/computer that does NOT have a default Sql Server instance?  The error you're getting leads me to believe that BCP can't connect to a default instance since you did not specify the -S parameter to force BCP to connect to a named instance.

Comment: I am not sure but I think it doesn't have a default instance, it's sql server 7

Comment: As I understand your question, the export FROM 7.0 works fine.  Your 7.0 instance would have to be the default instance for the BCP command to work without specifying the -S parameter, I'm talking about the second BCP - that's the one that's failing, correct?  That is Sql 2008 R2 correct?  Does it have a default instance or a named instance?

Comment: I am working with the default instance I think

Comment: The 2008 R2 instance is running on a completely different computer than the 7.0 instance - correct?  Verify, on the 2008 R2 instance, that you can indeed connect to the default instance.  On the 2008 R2 server, bring up SSMS and try entering a single period in the Server Name field - that would be the default instance - does SSMS connect?  Verify the 2008 R2 instance is actively running.  Again, the error message indicates that BCP can't connect to the default instance.  Try specifying the -S parameter (check the BCP documentation I linked to in my answer)

Comment: well they're both running on the same physical machine but the SQL Server 7.0 is running on a Windows 2000 Advanced Server VM, but honestly, I'm new to SQL Servers and I only know few basics, I honestly didn't understand what you said about the SSMS

Comment: So I have done some research and learned a little about sqlcmd, I managed to find the instance name thanks to the -S parameter you told me about, which is  the name of my machine slash SQLEXPRESS, I don't know if that is the default instance or not

Comment: so I changed the second command with:

Comment: it sounds like your 7.0 instance is the default, which is why you were able to run the first BCP successfully without the -S parameter.  The 2008 R2 is a 'named' instance, so the second BCP command would need to be BCP -S .\sqlexpress - (that's a period, back-slash and then sqlexpress)

Comment: thanks Scott, it really helped me, there's still an error but at least it's another error, it means I'm making a progress